# « Parier sur le hasard » (La Peste, Albert Camus)

Tags: sens, verbes, formulation-idiomatique

On ne trouve pas une confirmation de l'usage de la préposition « sur » avec « parier » dans le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/parier); le Larousse propose un exemple mais ce n'est rien qui semble convenir.

> ([Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/parier/58200)) 1. Mettre un enjeu sur un gagnant présumé à une épreuve sportive : Parier vingt euros sur un cheval.
>
> Synonyme : jouer

Le Wiktionnaire n'offre pas de meilleure solution.

> ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/parier)) Engager une somme au jeu et spécialement aux courses, dans l’espérance d’un gain.
>
> Parier sur un cheval, pour un cheval.

Sans aucun doute, selon cette définition l'expression ne signifie rien.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/hasard)) A. − Cause, jugée objectivement non nécessaire et imprévisible, d'événements qui peuvent cependant être subjectivement ressentis comme intentionnels.
>
> - Le hasard fait bien, mal les choses; la part qui revient au hasard; c'est le hasard; les fantaisies, l'intervention du hasard.

On peut parier sur une conséquence possible que le hasard entrainera, mais, littéralement, même en concevant qu'il s'agit d'un pari au sens figuré, pas sur le hasard.

Doit-on considérer que dans cette formulation le langage de Camus enfreint les bornes de ce qui est normalement accepté ou doit-on reconnaitre qu'une autre définition existe ? Que serait cette définition ?

---

*Le texte*

> C’est ainsi que ces
> hommes en vinrent à négliger de plus en plus souvent les
> règles d’hygiène qu’ils avaient codifiées, à oublier
> quelques-unes des nombreuses désinfections qu’ils
> devaient pratiquer sur eux-mêmes, à courir quelquefois,
> sans être prémunis contre la contagion, auprès des
> malades atteints de peste pulmonaire, parce que,
> prévenus au dernier moment qu’il fallait se rendre dans
> les maisons infectées, il leur avait paru d’avance épuisant
> de retourner dans quelque local pour se faire les
> instillations nécessaires. Là était le vrai danger, car c’était
> la lutte elle-même contre la peste qui les rendait alors le
> plus vulnérables à la peste, ils pariaient en somme sur le
> hasard et le hasard n’est à personne.

Comment: Une expression plus commune est "parier sur la chance", ce qui signifie que l'on espère que la chance sera au rendez-vous. On peut jouer au casino en *pariant sur le hasard* , c'est-à-dire en "misant" sur le fait que le sort soit favorable.

Comment: @Graffito D'après ce que vous dites l s'agirait d'une expression figée ; une recherche Google montre que « parier sur la chance » est d'origine très récente (https://www.google.com/search?q=%22parier%20sur%20la%20chance%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr). Elle proviendrait de la forme analysable « parier sur la chance de X », que l'on trouve aussi.

Comment: @LPH Pouvez-vous ajouter un peu de contexte? Le passage dans lequel Camus utilise cette expression?

Comment: @LPH Pour ce qui est de _sur_, n'est-ce pas la bonne préposition à utiliser par défaut avec le verbe _parier_? Comment diriez-vous autrement? On _parie sur_, et pas autrement.

Comment: @Frank On trouve les prépositions suivantes : « à, contre, avec » ; il y a la construction avec « que » aussi, mais « sur » n'est pas pris en compte dans le TLFi ; c'est pourtant un préposition très usitée dans le cas des jeux et sports et sa combinaison avec « parier » a un sens bien connu; ce n'est pas le problème, qui maintenant consiste à vérifier qu'il existe une expression figée (« parier sur le hasard »), et son sens exact.

Comment: @LPH _parier avec quelqu'un_, _parier contre une équipe_. Bon. _parier à_? Comme dans _parier aux courses_? Mais comment pariez-vous _sur_ quelque chose, si ce n'est avec la préposition _sur_?

Comment: _parier sur le hasard_ n'est pas une expression figée. C'est simplement une phrase, avec le verbe _parier sur quelque chose_. _Parier sur un mauvais cheval_, _parier sur une accalmie_, _parier sur un relâchement de la grève_...

Comment: @Frank Il y a au moins une idée de sens figuré puisqu'il est évident qu'il n'y a verbalement aucun pari de fait. Ensuite, vous semblez vouloir dire que « parier sur le hasard » c'est comme « parier sur un cheval » ; c'est archi-faux.

Comment: @LPH Ah bon? C'est faux? Pourquoi? Quelle est la différence?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146198/discussion-between-lph-and-frank).

Comment: Lire que « Camus enfreint les bornes de ce qui est normalement accepté » est très surprenant quand il suffit de constater l'emploi relativement courant de la formulation. Et pourquoi un pari serait uniquement verbal ???? On parie sur la vie, on parie sur le gouvernement, je suis sûr d'en trouver d'autres si je continue à fouiller.

Comment: @None D'abord, je ne dis pas qu'il enfreint les limites de ce qui est accepté, mais je demande si ce serait le cas ; secondement enfreindre les limites n'a pas à être un crime de lèse-majesté et peut à l'occasion résulter en une innovation bienvenue. Pour ce qui est de  la formulation, elle ne jouit pas d'un statu exceptionnel, c'est une formulation comme les autres et soit elle est analysable soit elle ne l'est pas. Je n'ai pas encore lu cette analyse dans ce qui a été dit. Il y a de fortes chances qu'elle n'existe pas et qu'il faudra une définition dans les dictionnaires.

Comment: @LPH "le Larousse propose un exemple mais ce n'est *rien qui semble convenir*" : ah ? pourquoi donc ?

Comment: @guillaume31 Ça me semble évident : comment peut-on considérer le hasard comme un _gagnant présumé_ ?

Comment: @LPH cette question découle d'une approche trop étroite de "parier". Il existe d'autres acceptions que la stricte action de miser sur un gagnant dans un jeu - voir II. B. dans l'entrée du TLFi.

Comment: @guillaume31 « [Le compl. prép. désigne un inanimé ou une pers., objet du pari] » : le hasard n'est pas un objet de pari ; il n'y a rien dans « II B » qui permette une analyse.

Comment: @LPH Vous oubliez la définition principale : "Engager une attitude, une opinion; prédire la réussite." Rien n'indique dans cette définition qu'il s'agit d'un jeu ou d'une compétition avec une victoire ou une défaite qui font l'objet du pari. Les exemples qui suivent la définition le prouvent aussi.

Comment: C'est justement pour cette définition principale que le complément de la préposition est l'objet du pari.

Answer (score 2):

Pas de problème ici: *parier sur le hasard* veut tout simplement dire qu'on s'en remet au hasard, qu'on n'essaie pas de dicter la suite des évènements, qu'on s'en remet à son sort pour ainsi dire, et qu'on *parie* que le hasard fera bien les choses, que tout ira bien, et que l'on va *gagner* en quelque sorte en *misant sur le hasard* (peut-être inconsciemment), même si l'on ne contrôle rien ou ne prend aucune action spécifique.

L'expression pourrait peut-être paraître bizarre, puisqu'après tout, quand on parie, il y a un élément de chance, et il pourrait paraître étrange de parier "sur le hasard" lui-même. Mais bien sûr, il n'a là aucune erreur, Camus (prix Nobel de littérature 1957) choisit ses mots, et il trouve une expression intéressante et suggestive, sans enfreindre aucune borne, ni avoir besoin d'aucune définition spéciale. Il faudrait aussi considérer l'aspect philosophique de cette expression, et l'importance du *hasard* dans la pensée de Camus. L'expression est intentionnelle car Camus veut nous faire réfléchir sur l'importance du *hasard* dans la vie.

Camus pourrait aussi vouloir dire que ces hommes parient sur le hasard alors qu'ils ne le devraient pas, car le hasard est... imprévisible. Ils font peut-être un mauvais pari en s'en remettant au hasard.

Pour ce qui est de l'expression, *parier sur le hasard* est simplement une phrase comme une autre avec le verbe *parier* (on peut souvent substituer *miser sur*) et pas une "expression figée", le sens n'a rien de spécial. Même si cela est surprenant, on peut parier sur... n'importe quoi - surtout si l'on écrit un roman ou un poème. L'objet du "pari" est habituellement introduit par les prépositions *sur* ou *pour*. On *parie sur* quelque chose quand on pense qu'on va *gagner* en faisant ce pari. *Parier sur* peut aussi signifier que l'on affirme que quelque chose va se produire, qu'on en est *certain*, et donc qu'on est prêt à parier dessus. Quelques exemples:

> parier sur un adoucissement du temps

> parier sur une accalmie/éclaircie

> parier sur un relâchement de la grève

> parier sur une baisse des prix

Comment: On peut s'en remettre à votre interprétation (acceptation du sort, quel qu'il soit) mais on peut aussi penser qu'il s'agit d'un espoir de passer à travers parce que le hasard ne peut pas nous viser en particulier ; les deux idées se valent pour autant que je puisse comprendre le contexte général. Alors, pourquoi une interprétation plutôt que l'autre ? Qu'est-ce qui vous apprend que la votre est la bonne ? Quelles sont les références que vous proposez ?

Comment: Non, non, non, je ne suis pas du tout d'accord avec votre nouvelle idée.

Comment: Ah bon? Quelle idée en particulier?

Comment: « croire que le temps va se radoucir », « croire qu'il va y avoir une accalmie », etc. Qu'allez vous dire ? « Croire qu'il va y avoir du hasard » ? C'est du non-sens.

Comment: @LPH Les expressions ci-dessus sont correctes et communes.

Comment: @LPH Ce n'est pas _croire qu'il va y avoir du hasard_, mais _croire qu'on a raison de parier sur le hasard_, de _miser sur le hasard_. Rien d'extravagant.

Comment: Je ne  leur reproche pas d'être incorrectes ; elles sont parfaitement correctes, mais elle ne sont pas de la même sorte.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146199/discussion-between-lph-and-frank).

Comment: @LPH ce n'est pas "Croire qu'il va y avoir du hasard" mais "croire dans le hasard", "croire que le hasard va jouer en notre faveur", autrement dit "miser sur le fait que le hasard va nous servir", donc "parier sur le hasard".

Comment: @guillaume31 Oui! J'ai bien mis ça dans ma réponse? LPH ne semble rien vouloir entendre ...

Answer (score 2):

Grevisse et Goosse ne s'en formalisent pas : « Le complément exprimant l'objet du pari est introduit par *pour* ou par *sur*  [...] *Ils parient en somme SUR le hasard* (CAMUS, *Peste*, p. 214) [...] ». (LBU14 § 294 f) Voir aussi le [*Rouleau des prépositions*](https://www.noslangues-ourlanguages.gc.ca/fr/le-rouleau-des-prepositions/parier) et la [BDL](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/24567/la-syntaxe/le-complement-du-verbe/parier-et-ses-complements).

Comment: Ben non, ils ne peuvent pas s'en formaliser, car c'est bien tout à fait correct :-)

Comment: Le tour laisse @LPH perplexe parce qu'on voit que Camus l'emploie comme si c'était un pari en bonne et due forme pour dire l'équivalent de _compter sur_ à mon avis. Mais la langue n'est pas une science exacte. Il y a flexibilité. _Parier sur le hasard_ est peut-être un peu anthropomorphisant, mais _parier sur_ (le joueur) c'est 1636 (DHLF/Rey).

Comment: Oui. Mais c'est peut-être bien un pari (inconscient) en "bonne et due forme": inconsciemment, ces hommes pensent qu'ils seront chanceux et échapperont à la peste même sans aucune protection sanitaire. Ils font un pari, dans le sens de _prendre un risque_. Le risque de gagner ou de perdre. L'emploi de pari par Camus ici n'est pas particulièrement remarquable.

Answer (score 1):

TLFi [Parier](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/parier)
–  1662 empl. abs. « faire un pari, prendre le risque de choisir » (Pascal, *Pensées*).

Le TLFi nous renvoie donc au pari de Pascal résumé ainsi sur [Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pari_de_Pascal#Pr%C3%A9sentation_sous_forme_d%27un_tableau) :

[image]

Tout comme Pascal prend le risque de parier sur l'existence de Dieu, d'autres parient sur le hasard, c'est à dire  prennent le risque de choisir le hasard.  Ou alors on peut aussi dire, comme @s.H.a.R.p.R.i.F.t, qu'ils *comptent sur le hasard*.

Pour ce qui est de l'emploi de **sur** [(TLFi](https://cnrtl.fr/definition/sur) IV A f) :

> f) [Le compl. désigne l'événement aléatoire qui sert de base à un pari] Miser, parier sur tel cheval. **P. ext. Spéculer sur une valeur, compter sur qqn.** Au fig. *Vous avez tiré une traite sur l'avenir, une traite à très longue échéance* (H. Bazin, Vipère, 1948, p. 273). (C'est moi qui souligne).

Pour comprendre le sens de **parier** dans des formulations comme [*parier sur le hasard*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22parier%20sur%20le%20hasard%22), [*parier sur la chance*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22parier%20sur%20la%20chance%22&tbm=bks&ei=uktsZJHRD-y8kdUPu76loAs&ved=0ahUKEwiRlou014r_AhVsXqQEHTtfCbQQ4dUDCAg&uact=5&oq=%22parier%20sur%20la%20chance%22&gs_lcp=Cg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzEANQgIUCWJyQAmD2kgJoAnAAeACAAWKIAYIEkgEBOZgBAKABAcABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz-books), [*parier sur l'avenir*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22parier%20sur%20l%27avenir%22), etc. on peut passer par un de ses synonymes donné par presque tous les dictionnaires : *miser*.

– Larousse :
[**parier**](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/parier/58200)

> verbe transitif indirect
> 2. Miser sur quelqu'un, quelque chose, mettre tous ses espoirs sur eux.

– Robert :
**Parier**. [Synonymes](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/parier).
jouer, engager, mettre en jeu, miser, risquer

– TLFi : [**Miser** (B 2)](https://cnrtl.fr/definition/miser/verbe)

> 2. *Au fig.*
>    a) Escompter la réalisation de quelque chose, la réussite de quelque chose ou de quelqu'un.
>    ♦ [Sans compl. dir.] Miser sur l'avenir; miser sur une oeuvre; miser sur la réussite de qqn; miser sur le succès de qqc.

– Le Robert : [Miser](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/miser) :

> familier *Miser sur*, compter, faire fond sur. *Miser sur un succès*.

Dans la formulation [*parier sur la vie*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22parier+sur+la+vie%22), parier est plutôt synonyme de *mettre en jeu* que de *miser*, c'est une question de contexte. *Parier* semble un terme plus générique que certains de ses synonymes.

Comment: Le hasard n'est pas un évènement, encore moins un évènement aléatoire.

Comment: @LPH  Il faudrait lire jusqu'au bout...  **P. ext.** et la suite...  l'avenir non plus n'est pas un événement.

Comment: Le pari de Pascal est un terme défini, ce n'est plus le sens propre de « parier » (Argument employé par Pascal…). Le hasard n'est pas quelqu'un, ni une valeur. Il ne s'agit pas de « parier sur l'avenir », mais de « tirer une traite sur l'avenir » ; cette rubrique à propos de « sur » n'est pas à propos de « parier ». D'ailleurs, « tirer une traite sur l'avenir » est une expression figée définie dans le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/traite) : « Au fig. (Tirer) une traite sur + subst. abstr. Prendre une assurance sur (l'avenir, la chance, etc.). ».

Comment: @LPH La question commence par la mise en relation de sur avec le verbe parier... donc regard sur les sens de *sur* ! Le sens propre de parier ? *Parier* a un sens assez large, donc tout dépend ce que toi tu appelles **sens propre**. En tous les cas il est clair que Camus ne parle pas de pari avec de l'argent. « Le hasard n'est pas quelqu'un, ni une valeur », oui bien sûr mais parier ne s'emploie pas  **que** sur  « quelqu'un » ou  une « valeur ».   L'existence de Dieu n'est pas plus quelqu'un ou une valeur que le hasard.

Comment: As-tu le même problème avec *betting on chance* en anglais. Parce que pour moi le rapport entre les mots est le même. Et j'ai déjà rencontré *betting on chance* et à priori (sans grande réflexion donc) j'utiliserais *bet on chance* pour traduire la phrase de Camus.

Comment: Je ne connaissais pas cette expression anglaise. Je n'en trouve pas de définition. D'après [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22betting%20on%20chance%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en), il semblerait qu'une définition soit nécessaire et elle serait « parier sur des évènement à chance égales de se réaliser ou non », mais il faudrait vérifier, et il pourrait y avoir plus d'une signification. (Subjects preselected for their knowledge of politics and lack of knowledge of football preferred betting on political events to betting on chance events that they considered equally probable )

Comment: @LPH C'est quoi le problème exactement à la fin? Camus a bien écrit "parier sur le hasard", il sait ce qu'il fait, et il n'y a pas d'erreur, d'expression figée avec un sens spécial ou quoi que ce soit de surprenant. On vous a expliqué en long, en large et en travers. De toute façon, on peut parier sur n'importe quoi, surtout dans un contexte littéraire. Un poète irait peut-être encore plus loin, pour parier sur des choses encore plus surprenantes.

Comment: @Frank Eh bien, finalement, quelqu'un arrive à la conclusion qu'il s'agirait au moins  d'un _petit oxymore_ ([user Guillaume31](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/63631443#63631443)). Il ne s'agit plus tout à fait du parangon de perfection auquel vous semblez vouer une confiance sans réserve.

Comment: @LPH Je ne vois pas bien quel est votre but dans tout cette discussion... C'est peut-être un jeu de votre part? C'est un oxymore? Bon. J'ai bien mis dans ma réponse que l'expression pouvait paraître suprenante ... mais oxymore ou pas, cela ne change rien à tout ce qui a été dit, et utiliser un oxymore en tant que figure de style n'est pas une _erreur_ du tout pour un auteur ...

Comment: @LPH … bien sûr, vous avez Raison !… comme J.Monod prix Nobel pour qui *l'intuition* validée par la physique quantique démontre que « tout ce qui existe est le fruit du hasard et de la nécessité ». A.Camus est un ‘héritier ̛ de Nietzsche, philologue et poète, pour qui « Ma seule ambition de poète est de recomposer, de ramener à l'unité, ce qui n'est que fragment, énigme, effroyable hasard. »

Comment: @Personne Je voulais explorer l'angle philosophique dans l'expression parier sur le hasard. Ce n'est probablement pas innocent de la part de Camus. C'est au contraire bien intentionnel, car Camus veut nous faire réfléchir au _hasard_.